# Which country has the most reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Just out of curiosity (and for fun), I looked at per-country reputation, and I post it here for reference.

Reputation sum of users whose *location* matched a key word (excluding users with <10 reputation; also excluding 101-reputation users in the second column):

```
key word     rep. sum  rep. sum   traffic   #users   #upv.   #downv.
                     (no 101-rep)

Iran            41469  34500                   165    3294      409
India           42871  24287       13.4%       488    4666      504
Pakistan        33998  12911        8.7%       432    1274      228
Canada          14929  12202        5.0%        63     935      306
United Kingdom  17487  11427       18.9%       166    1556      161
United States   16871  10306       19.3%       412    4437      439
Turkey          14050   9707                    94    2510      234
Malaysia         8519   6701                    38     362       32
Germany         10161   6222                    79     666       44
Bangladesh      12987   4099        2.2%       182     503       49
China            4412   4008                     8    2337       66
Emirates         6071   3950        3.5%        50    1101      238
Indonesia        6566   2728                   135     246       15
Australia        6094   2357        2.8%        57     197        7
Egypt            7476   2022                   115     213        7
Arabia           2424   1212        2.6%        31      45        0
Nigeria           152     51        2.2%         3       0        0
```

The "traffic" is the percentage of traffic [QuantCast](https://www.quantcast.com/islam.stackexchange.com#/geographicCard) assigns to each country.  "#upv." is the number of upvotes from users from a particular country, and likewise for "#downv.".  Computed using data explorer: [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/islam/query/620721) and [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/islam/query/42162) (and variations of these).

Interestingly, while the vast majority of downvotes come from users who don't list their country, the majority of upvotes come from users who did list their country.

Obviously, this is dependent on who lists their country in their profile, which is "noisy" data (it depends a lot on whether or not some high-rep user adds their country).  So don't weight this too highly.

Comment: ups Germany has less rep than I have ;) maybe because I'm only half German :).... oh I forgot to add my "noisy" data to my profile :D

Comment: Wow,my country is top in up and down votes ,rep sum :)