# How would a "question sandbox" work and how would it help the site?

Tags: discussion, questions

[Zaid](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2953/17163) suggested:

> For Mechanics.SE, I set up a [questions sandbox](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/25590) where I could unload questions that were floating around in my head but could not be asked immediately

and the first post in the sandbox (which was implemented as a chat room) says:

> Hello world! Every so often I find myself wanting to ask questions on mech.SE but fail to do so due to of lack of time, opportunity or simply because the question isn't developed enough. I was going to post this as a meta question but a chat format will probably serve the purpose better. Participation is most welcome.

I'm in the same situation here at times.  I write undeveloped questions in my phone, then develop them (e.g. add motivation and references), perform the usual checks (e.g. searching Google and the site for duplicates), and post them when I get back to my computer and when I have time.  I find the time delay helps write better questions too.

It's an intriguing idea, but...

**Question**: How would a "question sandbox" work and how would it help the site?

I'm also wondering how successful it was at Mechanics.SE.

---

**Update**: A trial run is here: [Draft question review [trial run]](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2966/17163)

---

Here's my current list.  I don't plan to keep this updated (I'll use the [Draft question review [trial run]](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2966/17163) thread instead), so some of these questions might be "done".

- Do left-handed converts need to start eating with their right hand?
- Is the amputation of body parts under sharia punishment performed under aesthetic?
- Do Sunni and Shia Muslims pray together during hajj?
- Is there a lesson to be learned from hijabi fetishists?
- Are pages of the Qur'an uniquely defined?  (E.g., the content of "page 5" does not vary from one printed version to another.)
- Why are punishments in the afterlife so gruesome, and not like, say, stubbing your toe, or having an itch you can't scratch?
- Why would a Muslim woman want to marry a gay man who has no sexual desire for her?
- If a layperson disagrees with a scholarly consensus, which should they do: obey Allah from their perspective, or disobey Allah and obey the scholars?
- What should one do about images of Prophet Isa popping up on Facebook?
- Why are headscarves not perceived as adornments?
- Are there hadith narration datasets available for scientific study through network analysis?

Assuming they're actually reasonable questions to ask, feel free to develop these into proper questions and post them (and maybe `<strike> ... </strike>` the questions out, so others don't post a duplicate).

Or let me know if there's a particular one you'd like me to post (that maybe you have a good answer for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from creating and experimenting with a chat room of your own.

> How would a "question sandbox" work and how would it help the site?

- "save" questions in progress
- get feedback for whether the question has the right level of detail or focus. The folks on codegolf.SE do a stellar job in their questions sandbox
- build up a pipeline of questions that can help sustain QPD above the required threshold for graduation during lean periods
- good questions facilitate good answers, which tends to drive stronger voting behavior

> I'm also wondering how successful it was at Mechanics.SE.

Mainly the question pipeline. We generated a lot of good questions and consequently site traffic drove up.