# what problems are with my question about aisha's marriage consummation?

Tags: discussion

this: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39974/is-there-a-hadith-which-clearly-states-that-when-aishas-marriage-was-consummate .

i think maybe really it was not unclear, but true/real reason for moderators were the large amount of links, but they are ashamed to uncover that.

it was closed as unclear and was not reopened after many editions.

if you think it is unclear, let read it word-by-word and show me in which place it becomes unclear, or in its first version.

or maybe moderators really think this is shamefool question.

i have known out now that fair answer could and should have a link to an article in wikiislam, an antiislamic website, as they already answered this question, so maybe moderators did not want to link to that site, for seo reasons, and for that closed my question.

Answer (score 3):

While I didn't vote to close, and I voted to reopen after editing, here's some feedback:

- *Why was it originally closed?*  It was unclear.  There's no doubt about this.  It seems you're only asking the question in the title.  Firstly, this is unexpected behaviour.  This was the original title:

  > is not it clearly not said about sex in the hadithes about aisha's marriage consummation?

  It's ungrammatical and unintelligible.  It certainly does not have the meaning of the current version of the title.  And people will be looking for the question in the post's body.  I would say it was a clear-cut case of "unclear what you're asking".
- *In its current form, why did it remain closed?*

  1. After editing the first time, it would have popped up in the reopen revision queue; it probably would not have attracted reopen votes after the first edit.  Subsequent edits wouldn't have bumped it to the reopen queue.

     It doesn't show now, but at the time, I recall multiple reopen votes (one was mine), but it looks like it didn't attract enough reopen votes.
  2. I'm guessing it failed to attract enough reopen votes because of:

     (a) the length of the post (e.g. you could have just picked one of the hadith and asked if "consummation" means "sex");

     (b) the "confirm my apologetics" question style.  The fact that this is on the Islam-critical site WikiIslam's page [The Meaning of Consummate](http://wikiislam.net/wiki/The_Meaning_of_Consummate) suggests its closeness to debate/apologetics; and

     (c) "consummation" literally implies "sex" in the English language:

     > In many traditions and statutes of civil or religious law, the consummation of a marriage, often called simply consummation, **is the first (or first officially credited) act of sexual intercourse between two people**, either following their marriage to each other or after a prolonged romantic attraction. -- [Consummation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consummation), Wikipedia

     so it's hard to imagine multiple hadiths were incorrectly translated.  It's quite possible that this is why it's still considered unclear.
  3. People here are simply doing other things.
- *Why was it deleted?*

  > deleted by Community♦ 2 days ago (RemoveAbandonedClosed)
  >
  > This question was automatically deleted. [Please see the help center for more information](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/roomba).
- *Also...*

  > if you think it is unclear, let read it word-by-word and show me in which place it becomes unclear, or in its first version.

  Acting confrontational like this is going to alienate the people you're asking help from.  Do you want it reopened, or do you want to start an argument?

All in all, **please put more effort into making questions understandable *before* posting them**.  Please make sure that the question being asked is obvious to the reader.  Consider also posting a draft [here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2966/17163) first for pre-review.

Comment: i said that there is no single term for "consummate", and asked just about hadiths. you edited my question, adding "consummate" in title and main part of question in post body. so you have made it more unclear. whether there is concept of "consummation" or not is a separate question. i did not ask about it. but my question was closed before you edited it.

Comment: i see the article on wikiislam first time now, and i am reading it now.

Comment: what apologetics do you see there? why do you regard/consider it that way? am i promoting some view?! - no! i have not promoted anything! no version of answer! or i slightly promoted both of 2 possible version of answers! that was not promotion, just i told what i thought. that is just an incomplete research effort. i am going to also look at lane's dictionary, but it is not done for now. if you look at tips at question voting buttons you will see "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear" and "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".

Comment: you say "It's ungrammatical and unintelligible" about the title. why it is so? can you prove? again, read it word-by-word and show me in which place it becomes ungrammatical or unintelligible.

Comment: "i did not ask about it." - this is not very true, that would be useful part of answer. but it would be an additional question, and i added it in comments, as reply to goldpseudo.

Comment: "Firstly, this is unexpected behaviour." - why do you think so? that seems to be just your way of writing , why do you require from other people to write as you? and it is your style to duplicate question in post body after something like "my question is:" with bold.

Comment: quran 4:23 answers my question. it is quoted in wikiislam. thank you. same root with same preposition is used there and it should mean sex. my question is pretty much answered.

Comment: but if it is controlled by somebody, from their point of view, they cannot check whether there was sex or not, they can account staying together alone as possible sex. so, "dahala gala" - "enter upon" - may theoretically mean even entering in a room to somebody and staying with him together alone.

Comment: " you edited my question, adding "consummate" in title and main part of question in post body " - this is wrong , i had used word "consummation" in question title from beginning.