# What should I do in order to get back my deleted question by someone? Why is my question deleted?

Tags: discussion, support

I saw my post “Can I ask Allah To reverse time till the moment He’ll decide to create Pen?” that was deleted this question, I know and I recognize that I did constant edits but this time I was trying to make 100% simple and clear question and then I no longer edit because I was trying to find out was to make 100% clear and I found this how to make, but my question is deleted? I don’t understand why and for how long will be deleted? And what should I do in order to get back my deleted question by someone? I’m sorry if it sounded”silly” and “disturbing” but it is only for me to know more and more, what’s wrong with knowing more? I have learned my mistake, and I’ll edit only few times next question and this one I no longer edit it.

Comment: Ask a new question or better post it here https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2966/draft-question-review-trial-run to have it checked before posting it on the main site! Or you can try to go the hard way and try to re-open it.

Comment: Ask a new question, but try to focus your question on one topic. The topic of your question has merit as 'Abdullah ibn Mas'ud (a major companion) used to [suplicate](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?hflag=1&bk_no=37&pid=811855) that if Allah had decreed him as from the people of hell to reverse His decree as [Allah eliminates what He wills or confirms](https://quran.com/13/39/).

Comment: @Medi1Saif Can you tell me and be clearly on how can I rep-on it?

Comment: @III-AK-III I can’t ask a new question because it appears:”We ca no longer accept questions from this account any longer”.

Comment: Sorry I guess you need some more reputation for this option, you can address it as you did, after editing it! But this is the longest option, as you may need to wait a peer-review and as your first drafts were bad I see no chance for a success.

Comment: @Medi1Saif if you see like this, what should I do? I shall wait until this message will be lifted or what?

Comment: Read my first comment I've given you 3 options and qualified them: option 1 ask a new question (easy IMO not best choice), 2. ask it in the linked meta post first and wait for comments to improve it (IMO best choice) 3. edit it and hope that somebody would notice and re-open it (as you don't have enough rep to start a re-open) (here I'd say good luck maybe in 10 years this would be the case, as without any improvement none will vote to re-open it)

Comment: @Medi1Saif And one thing, how can I see how much is the reputation? And with what reputation I need in order so that this message “ We can no longer accept questions from this account any longer” to get rid of it?

Comment: @Medi1Saif Or if I can have how many reputations then this message will be removed?