# Allow moderators to migrate a question to a right site

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I’m asking this because, I have been banned and I have some questions I’d like to ask in Islam Stack Exchange and when I’m trying to do that on Islam Meta, then it simply gets deleted instead of migration. In my opinion, I think it is a good way to improve your future questions, right? Because, I’m getting bored for waiting till the ban duration is over. What do you think about this? Good idea? Because, some posts like:

1. [How did our Prophet Muhammad (PBHU) die?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/44007/23833)
2. [What is the 'awrah between husbands and wives?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/46393/23833)
3. [Picture of husband and wife](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/46361/23833)
4. [Can human and jinn marry, and is it permissible?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35270/23833)
5. [Can we look at pictures of the deceased?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/46295/23833)
6. [Why is pork forbidden in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2192/23833)

Here, some of them I tried to give a good answer as he questioner wants but why it is down-voted? And some I have given a answer to the question and a down vote I get and someone else answered and sometimes it is the same as I answered. Where do I make a mistake? What should I do with posts that have 2 answers, one from me and one from someone else? Should I delete mine? Or what? Because, also deleting too many times does not do any thing, you know what I mean? Can you please edit this post including its question title if it is necessary? Please? I hope this one it is not a stupid question. Can you tell me or explain to me why I did got downvotes on these questions as I mentioned above? Some, I know the reasons but some I don’t know why. To be honest, I’m not really good in answering questions but I try only till I manage to give an excellent answer, and in one of my posts I don’t know how to edit them in a proper way. Please don’t judge me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's safe to assume that moderators are not going to conspire to circumvent the rules.  That's the opposite of what they do.  (They'd probably lose their diamond for that.)

---

One possibility is to post draft questions on [Draft question review [trial run]](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2966/17163).  The community can give you feedback.

> If you're unable to improve your existing questions, **you'll get the chance to ask one new one 6 months after your last question**. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.
>   <sub>[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)</sub>

Your last question was [Oct 22 '17](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/23833/alex-a) (five months ago).

Once the question ban wears off, it's best to make sure to ask a great question.  If people have up-voted (or down-voted) the draft, then they'll likely up-vote (or down-vote) the one on the main site.

---

*Update*:

## Please don't write plagiarized answers!!!

I've just looked at a random selection of your answers, and **more than half were plagiarized**.

> If you lack the expertise to answer a question on your own, leave the job to someone else. Plagiarized answers will be deleted without warning, potentially leaving a question unanswered.
>
> **It is never ok to pass off significant amounts of someone else's writing as your own**, not even temporarily. You wouldn't claim the words of your prophet as your own, would you? So why take credit for the words of your brothers?
>   [Shog9♦](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/302/17163)

Every single plagiarized answer needs to be deleted.

### Please save the users/moderators of this site the time by deleting plagiarized answers yourself.

---

It's a lot harder to write answers than one might think, and it takes time to get used to writing good answers.  (I'm hardly an expert myself.)

I'll take a look at the first question on your list: [How did our Prophet Muhammad (PBHU) die?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/44007/17163)  Here's my advice:

- The biggest problem with this is that it's hard to find an answer to the question: *How did our Prophet Muhammad (PBHU) die?*
- We need a laser-like focus on the question.  Get rid of the unnecessary material (= noise):

  - "In the name of God, the Most Merciful, Most Just" (say it out loud if that's important to you)
  - "Your question: How did prophet Muhammad(pbuh) died?"
  - "Answer:"
  - "General informations about prophet Muhammad:" and the long quote... it's not related to the question.
  - "And God knows best." x2 (This is sometimes appropriate for when they're a differing scholarly opinions and it's impossible to distinguish.)
  - "I hope this is a good answer"
- trim the long hadith back to include the relevant parts
- include a reference to where the hadith can be found so the reader can easily access it
- include the grade of the hadith (are they reliable?)
- it looks like [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=323047) was quoted without reference; this gives the impression of plagiarism (which is not only downvote-worthy, but the [moderators delete these](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/what-to-do-about-plagiarism)).
- avoid "It seems that..." in place of "[Islamic source] states that..." (and ideally confirm it with other Islamic sources)
- it looks like [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/71400) was also quoted without reference; also plagiarism (and consequently, we have no idea how you have knowledge of what the Angel of Death says)
- the two linked references are not reliable Islamic sources [QuestionsOnIslam](http://questionsonislam.com/article/it-appropriate-get-angry-angel-death-azrael-because-he-takes-away-our-souls) and [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeynab_bint_Al-Harith) (Wikipedia is good for definitions, background information, etc.)
- the Wikipedia link is to the mobile site
- references are more useful when they're placed inline (i.e., next to where they're needed in the text)
- This is the conclusion:

  > **Conclusion**: with regard of what Zainab did to prophet Muhammad, actually, it was God’s plan to do so. Because prophet Muhammad was very kind and he respects whatever God wishes and he offers daily prayers constantly and then God wishes that he will meet Him because God loves him so much. And whatever happens, do not say that this person is bad because God decides that way to happen, so that Ge can show or prove or to meet this person because of too much kindness and so on. And as for what happen at that time is because, the Jewish lady wanted to test him(pbuh) if he’s a real prophet or not.

  It doesn't answer the question *How did our Prophet Muhammad (PBHU) die?*  It feels like you're trying to push the reader into thinking something.

Another problem is that it overlooks the long time between the Prophet being poisoned and the Prophet's death; the answer suggests the Prophet was poisoned and died shortly afterwards.

It also doesn't acknowledge the existence of multiple scholarly views.

---

Some of your questions:

> Where do I make a mistake?

Firstly, writing a correct answer is the bare minimum expected.  It also needs to be easy to read, and supported by reliable references.  You can identify mistakes by cross-checking your answer with other resources.

> What should I do with posts that have 2 answers, one from me and one from someone else? Should I delete mine? Or what?

If your answer has gone into the "answer graveyard", it's probably not a bad idea to delete it (probably nobody is going to see it).  If you feel it still has value, don't feel obliged to delete it.

Comment: Does also self deleting the answered when is necessary, it won’t account as per READ EVERYTHING WE ARE WBOUT TO TELL YOU? Because, I don’t want to have problems with this also.

Comment: It wouldn't help you get out of an [answer ban](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans).

Comment: I think you’re right. But, where do you look in order to see when is the last post of each user? Just as you told me that the last post was in....

Comment: @goldPseudo: I'm not good with numbers.  (: