# Need advice asking the following question: where do Muslims find guidance for dealing with slander, mockery, and insults against Islam?

Tags: discussion

I find three places in the Qur'an with words that seem to apply:

7:200 - If a provocation from Satan should provoke thee, seek refuge in God

23:96-98 - Repel thou the evil with that which is fairer...And say: 'O my Lord, I take refuge in Thee...and I take refuge in Thee, O my Lord'

41:34 - Not equal are the good deed and the evil deed. Repel with that which is fairer and...he...shall be as if he were a loyal friend.

But the reactions I usually see (not counting fanatics) include anger, counter-insults, large-scale protests, and calls to make insult to Islam illegal, even calls to prosecute insult as hate speech, or worse.

I would like to ask, on the main site, where Muslims find their guidance for such reactions, and what interpretive technique they use for setting aside the aforementioned guidance toward repelling evil with that which is fairer.

I seek comments from the meta community, especially on the following two points, but any comments are welcome.

1. I think my question is within the guidelines for the main site; does anyone here disagree?
2. Might my question be taken as inflammatory on the main site? Does anyone here have any suggestions for cooling it down?

Comment: IMO the question might be a duplicate of [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/47010/20218).

Comment: Hey, thanks, that sheds a lot of light. But that one is asking specifically what is to be done, while I'm asking how they decide. A couple of people answering that question indicated how they decide, but I would like to ask the question specifically, and hopefully get more than one answer. Does that seem ok? Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I don't see anything wrong with this question.

What you might expect is that the question might have a rather negative acceptance. So maybe one should think of how to formulate it.
Note that we have our [draft-question](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2966/draft-question-review-trial-run) review for such matters.

However I'd be interested in an answer as I guess that -sadly- most Muslims are guided by their emotions in first place. And I'd wonder if there are any real techniques as interpretation is an open ended matter. Even if the osol al-Fiqh define some limits and guidelines.