# Idea- make a special site that has every site of SE and to be allowed there to discuss about corecting a post before posting to the real site

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I’m asking this because I have few problems when trying to write a good answer and question. Here’s few major problems that I’m facing:

1. unable to verify whether it is correct or not the question text.
2. Unable to detect any error from the text.
3. And, I don't know on each site how to write an excellent question and answer to each site.

And if this would happen, I’ll be very glad because I’ll finally be able to discuss with other users with very high reputations about a post, so that we can see if there are any spelling mistakes, grammar etc... that need to

And also, allow in that site to discuss about whether I have written an excellent question and answer to each site of SE before I post it to the real site. And allow on that site to discuss whether that question title is good or bad, and also to be allowed to discuss on ”how to write a good question title”

**Question:** Are you agreed to make this special site? What is your opinion about this?

Because some aren’t able to correct their own errors, and they need help in this.

Comment: What do you think [draft question review](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2966/draft-question-review-trial-run) is for?

Comment: Ok but, that's only for correcting. But what if I have no knowledge of see wether it is correct or not the way I have wrote?

Comment: Then post it there and wait for comments

Comment: @Medi1Saif But I want to post it in Meta just for discussion about correction of a post before I post it to the main site so that I won’t have to make others waste they time on correcting my post.

Comment: And what am I telling you from the beginning and even months ago: post it as an answer in the linked page!

Comment: You can also post About your question in [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3819/jaamiat-stackexchange-al-islamyya)

Answer (score 1):

We do not have the capabilities to do this here.  It's the type of thing that gets discussed at [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), but feature requests without much research (e.g., a prototype or supporting data) are not particularly well received.  Assigning programmers to implement and test such a feature costs money, so StackExchange is only going to do it if it's almost certainly worthwhile.

The closest feature I'm aware of is StackOverflow's [Review Queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review):  *Help and Improvement* and *Triage*.  The relevant meta discussion is: [Triage and Help & Improvement review queues at sites other than Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251737/triage-and-help-improvement-review-queues-at-sites-other-than-stack-overflow)  It's not exactly what you have in mind (it's more about new users), but it's the closest that might plausibly be implemented StackExchange wide within a reasonable timeframe.

In the meantime we have: [Draft question review [trial run]](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2966/draft-question-review-trial-run)

Also, spelling errors and grammar mistakes can just be *edit*ed without discussion.

Meta.SE is the suitable place for site-wide questions like [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title); see its [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).