# Two accounts banned from asking questions

Tags: discussion

Recently I have been undergoing problems. It has been related to timings, health problems and other curiosities which have left me asking questions. I ask but the answers I receive do not seem to be very satisfactory. I try my best not to repeat questions and ask questions in a correct manner. It may not be the most clear question but it was all that I provided and was enough. I have had two accounts banned from asking questions and now I can not even get an answer to my questions that I am currently curious about as well. It actually annoyed me and I try remaining calm. I dont even know what to do and who to ask questions any more because it just seems that I will get blocked or appointed for doing something incorrectly or just left alone with no answer. I am eager to learn and get solutions to serious problems that impact my lifestyle but it seems that the more I try the worse it becomes.

Why are there such frequent flags and bans on this?

Please keep in mind I am not trying to send or preach any form of hate I am just slightly irritated myself and seriously need solutions to my problems.

Comment: Also when I add or edit something even after I may have made a minor mistake nobody responds or says anything so it was just a complete waste of time

Comment: I have to keep making new accounts and dont want to keep creating emails just for this.

Comment: Saying there's no response on your questions simply is a lie! Just opening your first two questions show a lot of comments on your posts, any question that has been closed leaves a comment explaining why and what you should do. Creating multiple accounts is not a solution if you  don't care to understand how SE works and you seem to keep ignoring that.

Answer (score 5):

Browsing through your question history, not even counting your other accounts, your questions seem to be decidedly low quality. Many of then are nothing but one-liners, and for the most part they show little if any research effort, and a lot of them were closed as duplicates which suggests they could've been solved before asking with even a bit of time spent searching first.

Moderators have no control over question bans; it is a system-imposed restriction based on a continuing pattern of low-quality questions. It is typically not tripped unless a user is *consistently* making mistakes and failing to improve: If you find yourself tripping a question ban, you are doing something very wrong and need to fix your own behaviour before doing anything else.

Once tripped, pretty much your only recourse is to *improve* your existing questions so they attract upvotes and answers. Making new accounts just so you can continue to post bad questions is exactly the worst thing you can do: It is a waste of everybody's time, ours and yours, and very likely only going to end up with you banned from using the site at all.

I would highly recommend you read the help in the following links and take the advice to heart before attempting to post any new questions:

- [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/132874)
- [How do I ask a good question?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

When users who have been using the site longer than you give you advice, heed it. If you need help with formulating a question, you are free to ask for assistance in doing so in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=islam.stackexchange.com) or on Islam Meta here; we even have a [Question Sandbox](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2966/22) for exactly that purpose.

And above all else, *be patient*. Everyone here is a volunteer, expecting them to drop what they're doing just to spoonfeed you an answer to your question, no matter how important it seems to you, is just rude. Just take your time to formulate a question people *want* to answer and insha'allah the answers will come. Or better yet, take the time and make the effort to research the question yourself and post your own answer.

Comment: Nobody gives advice you are like the first. People just criticise. I try to do one liners to make it simple but when I write a lot nobody answers or they just dislike it and point out minor things. It just gets annoying. I may have tried to edit questions but this doesn't make a difference because nobody checks them anyway.