# Topics to which some reference questions could be useful

Tags: discussion, specific-question

We have lots of questions that are asked in a way or another rather frequently.

My intent with this post is seek some ideas and agreement on some topics that could fit.

We already have:
[Is X halal? (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36838/is-x-halal-reference-question),
[Which things break the wudu?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11103/which-things-break-the-wudu) a reference question for purity for wudu' ,
[Who are the women that a man is forbidden to marry?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/who-are-the-women-that-a-man-is-forbidden-to-marry)  one for women which are forbidden to marry and
https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/65541/will-allah-do-such-and-or-such-reference-question an attempt for a reference question on topics that are rather 'ilm al-ghayb.

Among the topics that I'd suggest for discussion is certainly:

- Is this kufr-questions or is this shirk-kufr-questions:
  https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/70026/please-answer-does-it-will-be-kufr
  https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/70005/is-this-kufr-please-answer-do-not-delete-my-question
  [Did I commit kufr?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/69730/did-i-commit-kufr)
  [What do I do in this case, is this Kufr?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/68928/what-do-i-do-in-this-case-is-this-kufr)
  [Doing black magic but you did not know shirk was a sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/68299/doing-black-magic-but-you-did-not-know-shirk-was-a-sin)
  https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/70129/is-this-a-word-of-kufr

**A [Is "X" kufr (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/70271/is-x-kufr-reference-question) was posted and can be answered now.**

---

**Edit:**
Some attempts to ask such reference questions:
[Kufr vs Shirk](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3537/13438)

Please vote and comment on the corresponding posts!

---

- There are other other topics that often pop-up like:
  taharah
  [are my clothes pure?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/69994/are-my-clothes-pure)?
  I've asked a question on this topic trying to make it a reference question: [How and when is it allowed to treat najasah on items -without water-?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62386/how-and-when-is-it-allowed-to-treat-najasah-on-items-without-water).
- Ta'aweez:
  https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/70091/aslamalikum-i-have-find-taveez
  we have a good question and answer on this topic:
  [What is the Islamic ruling regarding wearing charms or amulets?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/what-is-the-islamic-ruling-regarding-wearing-charms-or-amulets)
  It would be worth checking whether this answer/question is satisfactory or adding a new one (or several questions to fully address the topic) and maybe use this as a reference!
- Games vs reality:
  https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/70223/is-it-haram-to-build-the-earth-in-a-game-called-minecraft
  [Is League of Legends haram or halal to play](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/69629/is-league-of-legends-haram-or-halal-to-play)
  [Card games with points](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/69635/card-games-with-points)
- We also would need a post clarifying what Islam means by 'Uquq al-Walidyan عقوق الوالدين and Birr al-Waldiyan بر الوالدين because it is seemingly either translated by disrespect/respect or disobedience/obedience of the parents.

Please share your thoughts and maybe add some topics that could use a good reference question.

**Edit:** two suggestions:
please be pro-active

1. If possible ask the question and link it.
2. Else if not we could use the  [Draft question review [trial run]](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2966/draft-question-review-trial-run) post for elaboration of questions.

Answer (score 1):

We could use one for "**I did X will Allah forgive me?**"

Comment: Do you mind formulating such a question ... maybe as a draft?