# We just hit 84% answered!

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

[image: 84% unanswered]

Just a quick milestone post.

- **On May 5, 2017, we were at 80% answered** (19.56% unanswered rounded up).
- Today, which is **June 22, 2017, we are at 84% answered** (16.49% unanswered, rounded down).

In less than two months we've taken a chunk out of the unanswered questions.  Yay!

(Okay, we get nearly 1% just from rounding, but still...)

[Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14922/islam) writes:

> Okay – **90% answered is a healthy beta**, 80% answered needs some work. In the beta it's especially important that when new visitors ask questions they usually get a good answer.

I've been keeping track of if here: [Steps to reduce the number of unanswered questions](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2959/17163)

Comment: Great! Lets aim for 90% now

Comment: Thank you so much for editing all the old questions and queuing them up...

Comment: @Kilise I guess we must take the 85% hurdle first ;)

Comment: 83% actually either we should answer some question or close some more!

Comment: @Medi1Saif made it!!  https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2959/17163

Comment: Well done let's aim for 90%

Comment: @Medi1Saif Currently we need to resolve about 84 unanswered questions per percentage point.